# Missing glossaries entry despite using \glsaddall

Tags: glossaries, xindy

Some glossary entries do not show up. But I am using `\glsaddall`.
What am I missing here?

```
\documentclass[10pt,ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage[xindy,acronym]{glossaries}
\newglossary{symbolslist}{syiX1}{sygX1}{Symbolverzeichnis} 
\makeglossaries
\makeindex
\newglossaryentry{physical_t}{
type=symbolslist,
name={\ensuremath{t}},
description={text t}
}
\newglossaryentry{physical_dt}{
type=symbolslist,
name={\ensuremath{\Delta t}},
description={missing text delta}
}
\newglossaryentry{tau_k}{
type=symbolslist,
name={\ensuremath{\tau_k}},
description={text tau}
}
\newglossaryentry{gamma_k}{
type=symbolslist,
name={\ensuremath{\gamma_k}},
description={missing text gamma}
}
\newacronym{abc}{ABC}{the ABC thing}
\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long]
\printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=long]
\end{document}
```

After running

```
pdflatex MWE
```

the file MWE.sygX1 contains all four entries. Now running

```
makeglossaries MWE
```

creates MWE.syiX1, which contains only the entry for "tau_k" and "physical_t", but not "physical_dt" or "gamma_k".
Running

```
makeglossaries -n MWE
```

reveals:

```
makeglossaries version 2.15 (2014-07-30)
[..]
xindy  -L ngerman -C utf8 -I xindy -M "MWE" -t "MWE.glg" -o "MWE.syiX1" "MWE.sygX1"
```

As the xindy module for ngerman cannot be located, the effective call is

```
xindy  -L general -I xindy -M "MWE" -t "MWE.glg" -o "MWE.syiX1" "MWE.sygX1"
```

as far as i can see, the missing entries were both assigned to the "default" letter group by xindy. (this was seen by directly invoking xindy and examining the logfile MWE.glg afterwards)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you don't use `xindy` for the glossaries it will work. Thanks for the working MWE!

Comment: I think this is some `xindy` problem

Comment: There's also some problem with `style=long` that produces `Overfull \hbox (4587.61314pt too wide)`, though this seems unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation **why** it happens is as follows:
xindy makes use of [merge-rules](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/xindy/manual-2.html#ss2.2) that bring differently formatted keys into a canonical form.
The file "/usr/share/xindy/base/tex.xdy" contains:

```
(merge-rule "\\[a-zA-Z@]+ *" "" :eregexp)
```

Therefor "\Delta" and "\gamma" are dropped.
Now there is key clash:

- "\Delta t" == "t" and

  "\gamma_k" == "\tau_k".

As there are now only two keys, xindy picks one entry for each key and is done.

I suppose this behavior is not intended by the authors of "tex.xdy".
I am not deep enough into the subject to tell whether a sort-rule would fit better.

My way to **get around it**:
provide each entry with sort=.. making it unique by adding trailing gibberish.

```
\newglossaryentry{physical_dt}{
  type=symbolslist,
  name={\ensuremath{\Delta t}},
  sort={\ensuremath{\Delta t}uniqtrailer01212},
  description={missing text delta}
}
```

Comment: As I wrote in a previous comment: Use the more traditional `makeindex`, i.e. omit `xindy` for the `glossaries` here. I am no `xindy` expert too

Comment: pointed [xindy] mailing list towards this entry. Thank you Christian.